# changing font makes + combine strings instead of adding values

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$num1 = 10;
$num2 = 15;

echo "<font color='red'>$num1 + $num2</font>"  . "<br>";

?>
```

I expect it to equal "25",  when I add a font color it equals "10 + 15". Why?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do math inside a string. Instead, close the string. perform your addition operation, and concatenate the result.

```
echo "<font color='red'>" . ($num1 + $num2) . "</font><br>";
```

As [Orangepill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2364629/orangepill) wisely [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799769/variable-another-variable-which-has-a-different-font-color/16799807#16799807), this can be accomplished more efficiently like this:

```
echo "<font color='red'>",($num1 + $num2),"</font><br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
echo "<font color='red'>$num1 + $num2</font>"  . "<br>";
```

to

```
echo "<font color='red'>",($num1 + $num2),"</font><br>";
```

Comment: Since when is ',' the concatenation operator? ;)

Comment: it's not ... it's preferred over concatenation.... it's valid echo syntax and actually more memory efficient

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: Yes, this is valid echo syntax.

Comment: Interesting. Learn something new everyday.

Comment: with `.` you are creating an intermediate variable to hold the concatenated string so it's kinda like saying `$a = "Hello"; $a.= "World"; echo $a;` whereas using , it's like `echo "Hello"; echo "World";`

Comment: if $a and $b are big strings it could cause a memory issue because for a breif period of time peak memory usage for `echo $a.$b;` is going to reflect holding `$a + $b + ($a+$b)` whereas with the comma it's just `$a + $b`

Comment: You should also check out the difference between `echo "a" . 1 + 2 . "b";` and `echo "a" , 1 + 2 , "b";`

Comment: @andrewsi and that's why I always use parenthesis

Comment: @Orangepill - and so do I, now. After spending half a day tracking that little gotcha down. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate your string otherwise math will not work

```
echo "<font color='red'>".($num1 + $num2)."</font>"  . "<br>";
```